# how to save redundant calculations for coupled classes with composition

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have several classes that are coupled to each other and I would like to have a design that minimizes redundancy in them.

Right now the design is as follows. The classes are

- A
- C, D
- AC, AD: compositions of (A, C) and (A, D)

where all classes are initialized with the same data, each class performed some calculations and saves its own result. More specifically, users would create instances of A, AC, AD but not C and D. In other words, to the user, A, AC, AD are similar things and have uniform interface, whereas C and D are hidden. Here the logic is that, for example, the result of C is not useful unless we exclude the result of A from it. Some mock-up code is as follows

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        # some work
    def postproc(self, *args):
        # some real work
        self.result = ..

class AC(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.a = A(data)
        self.c = C(data)
    def postproc(self, *args):
        result_a = self.a.postproc(*args[:3])
        result_c = self.c.postproc(*args[3:])
        self.result = exclude_c_from_a(result_a, result_c)
```

With the current design, if the user create instances of A and AC, (or AC and AD, or other combinations), the calculation of A is done multiple times. I would like to have no redundant calculations, how should the design be changed?

A little more details on the usage: there will be multiple instances of A with different initial data too. Thus I cannot use singleton to guarantee there is only one A instance.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a functor with some internal caching mechanism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used memoization as the solution.

```
def memoize(func):                                                                 
    """                                                                             
    Decorator for memoization. Note the func arguments need to be hashable.         

    @type func: a callable                                                          
    """                                                                             
    memo = func.memo = {}                                                                                                                                              
    @wraps(func)                                                                    
    def wrapper(*args):                                                             
        if args not in memo:                                                        
            memo[args] = func(*args)                                                
        return memo[args]                                                           
    return wrapper
```

And it can decorate the class definition

```
@memoize
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...
```

such that for the same input arguments, only one instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

> how should the design be changed?

1. Just pass A and C to the constructor of AC so that you don't have to instantiate A and C in the constructor.
2. Don't pass data to the constructor of A. Instead, pass a result to the constructor of A. You should prevent to do any work in the constructor other than setting up the dependency.
3. Create a class that is only responsible for calculating the result.